# VC++ makefile project never up to date

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, nmake

Building a makefile project with Visual Studio 2013 always outputs "========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========", even though the nmake output is all up to date.  It's not actually building anything, but VS doesn't know that.  Is there any way to force VS to understand that nmake didn't actually do anything, and display the build output as up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Solution Explorer and select the project you want to build by itself when some changes occur for both debug and release mode.

Comment: I don't see how that will help.  I have 259 projects and when everything is up-to-date, I would like visual studio to understand that and not build anything at all.